# Dynamically add a servlet or refresh existing servlet mappings after the spring boot application has deployed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

I need a simple API proxy for my spring boot application that create proxy mappings based on the values coming from the database. I found this API proxy https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet which is simple and serves my purpose

To only way I found to create a dynamic proxy servlet is as below.

```
@ManagedBean
public final class ExecutorListener implements ServletContextInitializer {

private static final String TARGET_URI = "targetUri";


@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
EndpointsRepo endpointrepo = springContext.autowireBean(EndpointsRepo.class);
List<Endpoint> endpoints = endpointrepo.findAll();
for(Endpoint endpoint: endpoints){
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(endpoint.getEndpointCode(), new ProxyServlet());
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.setInitParameter(TARGET_URI, endpoint.getEndpointUrl());
    dispatcher.addMapping(endpoint.getUrlPattern());
}

}
```

The proxy now works fine as expected except if i update the mapping values in DB, i need those to be reflected in the dynamic proxy.

Is there any way to refresh the servlet mappings without restarting the spring boot application? I tried using applicationcontext.refresh() but it caused by DB datasource giving a message as unable to shutdown and causing a memory leak.

If i try adding a bean in runtime with SpringServletRegistration, the created mappings are not working. it seems the servlet mapping works only if i configure the servlets before onstartup as said by spring servlet documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add additional servlets after the initialization phase as it is forbidden by the Servlet API specification (cf. [Java Servlet Specification, Version 4.0](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf)). In section 4.4, while talking about the `ServletContext#addServlet` methods it says:

> These methods can only be called during the initialization of the application either
> from the `contexInitialized` method of a `ServletContextListener`
> implementation or from the `onStartup` method of a
> `ServletContainerInitializer` implementation.

You can still reuse the `ProxyServlet` class, but you'll need to write your own servlet (mapped to `/*`), which will create many instances of `ProxyServlet`, configure them and route the requests to the right one.

**Edit:** Basically you need a class like this:

```java
public class MetaProxyServlet extends HttpServlet {

   /**
    * To configure a {@link ProxyServlet} without modifying its code.
    */
   private static class ProxyServletConfig implements ServletConfig {

      private static final String  P_TARGET_URI = "targetUri";
      private final String         targetUri;

      @Override
      public String getInitParameter(String name) {
         return P_TARGET_URI.equals(name) ? targetUri : null;
      }
      // Other methods
   }

   /**
    * Serves to modify the pathInfo of the request.
    */
   private static class RewrittenServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

      private final String pathInfo;

      @Override
      public String getPathInfo() {
         return pathInfo;
      }
      // Other methods
   }

   private TreeMap<String, ProxyServlet> proxyServlets = new TreeMap<>();

   /**
    * Adds a reverse proxy between {@code pathPrefix} of this servlets namespace
    * and {@code targetUri}.
    * 
    * @param pathPrefix
    *        must start with '/'
    * @param targetUri
    *        URI to be proxied
    * @throws ServletException
    */
   public void addRedirect(String pathPrefix, String targetUri) throws ServletException {
      final ProxyServlet servlet = new ProxyServlet();
      servlet.init(new ProxyServletConfig(pathPrefix, getServletContext(), targetUri));
      proxyServlets.put(pathPrefix, servlet);
   }

   @Override
   protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();
      Entry<String, ProxyServlet> entry = proxyServlets.floorEntry(pathInfo);
      // entry.getKey() precedes, but not necessarily is a prefix for pathInfo
      if (entry != null && pathInfo.startsWith(entry.getKey())) {
         String rewrittenPathInfo = pathInfo.substring(entry.getKey().length());
         entry.getValue()//
              .service(new RewrittenServletRequest(req, rewrittenPathInfo), resp);
      } else {
         resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
      }
   }

}
```

The complete code is on [gist](https://gist.github.com/ppkarwasz/925520383962ea37aa3025882f71640a).

Comment: I tried that one but i'm getting 302 redirect as the response always

Comment: 302 redirects are probably generated by the proxied site. `ProxyServlet` doesn't deal with relative redirects properly. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: can you explain me how to use your code in spring boot? is this any different from the servlet config except redirect?

Comment: It's a `Servlet`, so you can register it in many ways (cf. [Baelung](https://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet)) and map it to e.g. `/proxy/*` (didn't test with other mappings). Once you get hold of it in your code you can call e.g. `servlet.addRedirect("/google", "https://www.google.com")`. I tested it on Tomcat, but from Spring Boot it should work the same.

Comment: from where do i call the servlet.addRedirect ? i registered it as a servlet using @WebFilter(urlPatterns ="/proxy/*") but how can i dynamically specify the target url?

Comment: Use the `ServletRegistrationBean` approach, so that the servlet is visible from Spring's `WebApplicationContext` and you can wire it to your business classes. The `@WebServlet` annotation registers a servlet with the server's `ServletContext`, but it is impossible to retrieve it from there.